# Why CMD17 cannot return 0xFE?

Tags: spi, sd

I have a problem with CMD17 when I send this command and wait response I always get first response 0x00 but when I am waiting at 0xFE it cannot get it. In debug mode I get 0xFE. This my code for reading data from card:

```
bool readDataCard(){
  int iteration = 0;
  U8 result = 0xFF;
  CS_SD = 0;

  //cmd17
  sendDataSPI (0x51, 0x00000000, 0x55);
  while (result != 0x00 && iteration < 10) {
    SPI1DAT = 0xFF;
    while ((SPI1CFG & (0x80))) ;
    result = SPI1DAT;
    iteration++;
  }
  if (result != 0x00) return false;

  while (result != 0xFE && iteration < 10){
    SPI1DAT = 0xFF;
    while ((SPI1CFG & (0x80))) ;
    result = SPI1DAT;
    iteration++;
  }
  if (result != 0xFE) return false;

  for(iteration = 0; iteration < 512; iteration++){
    SPI1DAT = 0xFF;
    cardData[iteration] = SPI1DAT;
    while ((SPI1CFG & (0x80)));
  }

  SPI1DAT = 0xFF;
  while ((SPI1CFG & (0x80))) ;
  SPI1DAT = 0xFF;
  while ((SPI1CFG & (0x80))) ;

  CS_SD = 1;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. You expect others on this platform to support you with solving the problems you face. You should make sure, that this will be as easy as possible. Your post is missing a lot to be answered effectively. Please add full information about the platform used and provide schematics about the wiring of the hardware. Please describe the funtionality of the surrounding code in a few words, too.

Answer (score 1):

The card may take quite a while to locate a sector, as it uses wear leveling internally (or at least should do so).

That means your iteration counter

`while(result != 0xFE && iteration < 10){`

is *several* orders of magnitude too small.

I recommend using one of the open source FAT implementations rather than trying to roll your own. Check your MCU vendors application notes - usually there is one implementing FAT on SD cards.